# How do I get a report of count of kubernetes containers over time in Azure Log Analytics

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics

I am trying to get a chart in a dashboard with the count of kubernetes containers over time for an application hosted on Azure. The application has multiple types of containers for different services under the application and I want to see count of pods against each service over time under the particular namespace for the application.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with

```
KubePodInventory
| where Namespace == 'namespace' and isnotempty(ServiceName) and ContainerStatus in ('running')
| summarize NumPods=count() by LogTime=bin(TimeGenerated, 1m), ServiceName
```

You will get the number of pods against each service under the namespace